# Networkx: colour nodes differently only when certain attribute determining the colour is present

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

While I am building a networkx graph, I algorithmically sometimes add a custcol attribute only to a few of them such as:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ('A','B'),
    ('B','C'),
    ('C','D'),
    ('D','E'),
    ('F','B'),
    ('B','G'),
    ('B','D'),
])

# in real life the following would be an algorithm deciding if the node
# should be custom coloured, and which colour it should get
G.nodes['C']['custcol'] = 'red' # simple setting for the example

# now let's explore the created example nodes
for node in G.nodes(data=True):
    print(node)
```

which would print out:

```
('A', {})
('B', {})
('C', {'custcol': 'red'})
('D', {})
('E', {})
('F', {})
('G', {})
```

I am now displaying the network with a single draw such as:

```
NXDOPTS = {
    "node_color": "orange",
    "edge_color": "powderblue",
    "node_size": 400,
    "width": 2,
}
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, **NXDOPTS)
```

which would generate the following picture:
[image: graph coloured with default parameters]
What would be the best/pythonic/more efficient way of drawing node 'C' (in this example) with the colour of its *custcol* attribute? Of course this in reality will need to be applied to a few dozen nodes with a few different colours that are decided case by base when creating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the node data, and create a list of corresponding colors:

```py
NXDOPTS = {
     "node_color": [data["custcol"] if "custcol" in data else "orange" for _, data in G.nodes(data=True)],
     "edge_color": "powderblue",
     "node_size": 400,
     "width": 2,
}
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, **NXDOPTS)
```

[image: custom coloring networkx nodes]

Comment: That works well, thanks. Is it NECESSARY to iterate or there's some more "vectorial"/pythonic approach? (my think skull has problems with list comprehensions :( must find a better tutorial)

Comment: With standard python, a list comprehension is the most "pythonic".  For vectorization, there is numpy, but you'd still need iteration to check each of the dictionaries.  Iteration without list comprehension would lead to longer code.  Once you're used to list comprehension, it also looks easier to understand (and thus "more pythonic").

Comment: Thanks @JohanC I am absolutely convinced of what you say but for whatever reason I'm kind of not "getting" it and when I stumble on one as an example I usually transform it in explicit iterations and ifs that I can inspect/debug. My limit. Hope to overcome it :) Happy winter festivities.